# How can get I get relational data from another table and calculate the average in Qlikview?

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, ss, qlik-expression

I have relationship with 2 tables

Table 1 - **Process**

[image]

Table 2 - **Process History**

[image]

Here the relationship is Id(Process table) and ProcessId(Process history table)
I want to calculate the Average Networking days of all the processes.

For eg:

```
nwd = 0;
count = 0;
if(Process.Id = ProcessHistory.ProcessId && ProcessHistory.Status='Status 3') {
  nwd += NWD(Process.CreatedOn, ProcessHistory.CreatedOn);
  count++;
}
```

Expected result AverageNWD = nwd/count;

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In the script:**

Using the script below will add a new field to the `Process` table - `NetWorkingDays`. This field will contain the working days for each project (`Id`). With this field in the dataset will be easier to calculate the average in the UI (something like `sum(NetWorkingDays) / count(distinct Id)`

```
Process:
Load * Inline [
Id, Name    , CretedOn
1,  Process1, 2019-04-02
2,  Process2, 2019-04-05
3,  Process3, 2019-05-02
4,  Process4, 2019-06-02
];


ProcessHistory:
Load 
  Id        as ProcessHistoryId,
  ProcessId as Id,
  Status,
  CreatedOn as ProcessHistoryCreatedOn
;
Load * Inline [
Id, ProcessId, Status  , CreatedOn
1,  1,         Status 1, 2019-04-02
2,  1,         Status 2, 2019-04-02
3,  1,         Status 3, 2019-04-04
4,  2,         Status 1, 2019-04-05
5,  2,         Status 3, 2019-04-06
6,  3,         Status 1, 2019-05-07
7,  3,         Status 3, 2019-05-09
8,  4,         Status 1, 2019-06-02
9,  4,         Status 2, 2019-06-04
10, 4,         Status 3, 2019-06-07
];


TempTable:
Load
  Id,
  min(CretedOn) as MinCreatedOn
Resident
  Process
Group By
  Id
;

join (TempTable)

Load
  Id,
  max(ProcessHistoryCreatedOn) as MaxCreatedOn
Resident
  ProcessHistory
Where
  Status = 'Status 3'
Group By
  Id
;


NetWorkingDaysData:
Load
  Id,
  NetWorkDays(MinCreatedOn, MaxCreatedOn) as NetWorkingDays 
Resident
  TempTable
;

Drop Table TempTable;
```

The last part of the script (from inside out):

Create temporary table to calculate `min(CreatedOn)` from `Process` table and `max(ProcessHistoryCreatedOn)` from `ProcessHistory` table. `ProcessHistory` is also filtered to include only records where `Status = 'Status 3'` (both tables are aggregated per `Id`)

```
TempTable:
Load
  Id,
  min(CretedOn) as MinCreatedOn
Resident
  Process
Group By
  Id
;

join (TempTable)

Load
  Id,
  max(ProcessHistoryCreatedOn) as MaxCreatedOn
Resident
  ProcessHistory
Where
  Status = 'Status 3'
Group By
  Id
;
```

Once the temp table is created we can create the final table that in which we will calculate the number of net working days using the [NetWorkDays](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/April2019/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/DateAndTimeFunctions/networkdays.htm) function. The `NetWorkingDaysData` table will have only two fields - `Id` and `NetWorkingDays`

```
NetWorkingDaysData:
Load
  Id,
  NetWorkDays(MinCreatedOn, MaxCreatedOn) as NetWorkingDays 
Resident
  TempTable
;
```

And the final step is to drop the `TempTable` - its no longer required

**In the UI:**

The same result can be achieved in the UI using the expression below. **Just bear in mind that the UI approach might lead to higher resource consumption!** Since all the calculations are on-the-fly (depends how big your dataset is)

```
avg(
  Aggr(
    NetWorkDays( min(ProcessHistoryCreatedOn) , max( {< Status = {'Status 3'} >} ProcessHistoryCreatedOn) )
  , Id)
)
```

Comment: Stefan, Thanks for your valuable answer. Will try this and update you. I have a question  min(ProcessHistoryCreatedOn) as MinCreatedOn,
  max(ProcessHistoryCreatedOn) as MaxCreatedOn - Both are taken from ProcessHistory table. But my requirement is Min needs to be taken from Process.CreatedOn. Also the ProcessHistory.CreatedOn needs to be taken when Status='Status 3'. So it will be more helpful if you edit your answer accordingly

Comment: @Prince updated the answer to include your comment. Out of curiosity ... why the Min CreatedOn should be taken from the Process table?

Comment: @Stephen Stoichev, Actually I want to take the NWD between the entry in Process table and the 'Status 3' entry in ProcessHistory table (ProcessHistory 'Status 1' entry can be a different date than the Process table entry.